# The inflection of "dies-" when "dies-" is used after "all-" (2 adjective; alle diese Bestrebungen…)

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending, definite-article, inflection

I have learnd the inflection of "all-".  
It is a kind of definite article(I'm not meaning that it is a definite article), so its inflection as adjective is..

```
m. n. f. pl.
er es e  e
es es er er
em em er en
en es e  e
```

And the pronoun is..

```
Mensch(pl.)  Ding(n.)
alle         alles
aller        alles
allen        allem
alle         alles
```

I knows when "all-" is used as adjective, the following another adjective has definite article adjective inflection like..

```
m. n. f. pl.
e  e  e  en
en en en en
en en en en 
en e  e  en
```

For example:

```
Aller guten Dinge sind drei.
Fast alle falsch geparkten Autos behindern den Verkehr.
Ich wünsche dir alles Gute.
```

But i don't know why "dies-" after "all-" just follows the inflection of definite article.

```
Er passt auf alle diese Kinder auf.
Er hat sich aller dieser Kinder angenommen.
Sie behauptete, dass alle diese Aussagen falsch seien.
```

It is first time that i see "all-" and "dies-" used together.
Is it because that the "dies-" is a kind of the definite article like "all-", so it has such inflection not like another normal article..?  
I'm assuming so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jacob Lee-Hart said, *dies-* is a determiner like *all-*. Some determiners allow to be combined with a second determiner:

- alle meine Entchen (children song)
- in diesem unserem Lande
- eine solche Unverschämtheit
- Ein jedes Kind ist einzigartig.

Determiners always keep their endings, they are not declined like adjectives.

One big problem is to distinguish between determiners and adjectives. There is no general rule, the definition is circular: If it's declined like an adjective, it is an adjective, and if it declines like a determiner, it is a determiner. Nevertheless there are determining adjectives like *ander-, viel-, sämtlich-, nächst-* and many others. The determiner question is one of the most discussed problems in (German) grammar.

However you will have to learn by heart the few possible combinations.

Another problem is, that for a generally possible combination you cannot build all cases in both singular and plural after the same pattern. For *all-* and *mein-* it would be

Singular

- all mein Geld (and not **alles mein Geld*)
- all meines Geldes *or* all meinen Geldes (and not ??*alles meines
  Geldes*)
- (mit) all meinem Geld (*mit allem meinem Geld* seems possible for me)
- all mein Geld (not **alles mein Geld*)

Plural

- all meine Sachen / alle meine Sachen
- all meiner Sachen  (?*aller meiner Sachen*)
- (mit) all meinen Sachen / (mit) allen meinen Sachen
- all meine Sachen / alle meine Sachen

Again you will have to learn by heart the possible combinations. The short form *all* can only be combined with determiners, not with adjectives: *all die schöne Musik, all diese netten Leute, all jener Ärger, all mein/dein/sein... Hoffen und Sehnen*, but not **all wichtige(n) Leute*, instead it is *alle wichtigen Leute*. Likewise you say *alle verlorene Zeit* and not **all verlorene Zeit*.

To express the same idea as *all- mein-*, we have a colloquial alternative:

Singular

- mein ganzes Geld
- meines ganzen Geldes
- (mit) meinem ganzen Geld
- mein ganzes Geld

Plural

- meine ganzen Sachen
- meiner ganzen Sachen
- (mit) meinen ganzen Sachen
- meine ganzen Sachen

Answer (score 1):

Dies- is not an adjective, in the meaning you listed it is a determiner. Determiners have their own declensions separate from adjectival endings, and dies- always has declines like the definite article.

> Er passt auf alle diese Kinder auf

Accusative plural, dies-e.